# Firebase + Ask Permission From User Before Adding This User To The List

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am in the process of creating an android application which uses Firebase. I am actually new to Firebase and I was searching on how to do the below features. I couldn't find a specific answer or the ones I found, I couldn't understand them well. If anyone can answer them, I will really appreciate it. :)

**Features:**

**Feature 1**: In my application when User A adds User B. I want the User B to get a notification, something like, "User A wants to add you as a friend." If User B confirms it then and only then should User B be added to User A's "friend-list" and vice-versa. If User B rejects, then the opposite should happen. Also, when User B removes User A from the "friend-list", both of them should be deleted from each other's "friend=list" and a notification of the said should happen.

**Feature 2**: I want the same to happen now but this time I want User Z to be the admin of User B and now when User A wants to add User B. The notification should go to User Z as well as User B. But rejecting it or accepting it should depend on User Z alone. So here it's between User A and User Z.

I want to know if I should use triggers in the Firebase database to achieve this or should I use the 'Security Features' of Firebase. I am sure there is a way to do this. I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is quite a lot to do for a single question. I would break it down into some components and go from there.

**Add User/Accept/Deny/Delete**

```
root/users/userId
root/userFriends/userId/friendUserId:true
root/userFriendRequests/userIdReceiver/userIdSender:true
```

List friend requests using a IndexAdapter.

If the user accepts:

```
delete /userFriendRequest/userId/theirUserId
create /userFriends/myUserId/theirUserId:true
create /userFriends/theirUserId/myUserId:true
```

If the user denies:

```
delete /userFriendRequests/myUserId/theirUserId
```

If the user deletes a friend:

```
delete /userFriends/myUserId/theirUserId
delete /userFriends/theirUserId/myUserId
```

**Send Notifications for Request/Added/Deleted**

For this you will need a app server using Firebase Admin.

If you delete a friend:

```
create root/requestNotificationDeleted/targetUserId/myUserId:true
```

Listen to requestNotificationDeleted using ChildEventListener
if a child is added,
you have targetUserId, and myUserId.

```
- Get the User data for myUserId using ListenerForSingleValueEvent
- Construct a notification using FCM, using the user data.
- Send the notification to targetUserId via token.
- Delete the child you just listened to, as the notification was sent.
```

You will need to connect userId/tokens either in a database, like your appserver or possibly your firebase.

By the same logic you can handle notifications for accepted, request, etc..

**Firebase Security**

You will want to setup security rules to enforce that no user can directly add themselves as a friend, etc.. So use them aswell.